# How to execute javascript after after ajax call inside a on() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to execute a $.ajax() inside a function called by a .on() method, so that in the newlly attached data, it would be possible to execute a script on a .click() event - I know this is probably something similar to other requests, but i have tryed and tryed, and can't find what is wrong withthe code...

The ajax function is called by a change in a select, and 'this' is passed as a variable to the function.

The data is correctly inserted inside the targeted div, but it seems that there is no bubbling, because no javascript runs from it (but runs outside of targeted div).

I used .on() so it would bubble up, and update the DOM, and I dont see wath I am doing wrong with it...

The ajax is called with:

```
$("body").on("change", "[data-project-ajaxSelect='true']", {select: this},Select_AjaxCall);

function Select_AjaxCall(event) {

    $select = event.data.select;

    if (typeof $select.data === "undefined" || $select.data === null) {
        var $select = $(this);
    }



    var options = {
        url: $select.attr("data-project-action"),
        type: $select.attr("data-project-method"),
        target: $select.attr("data-target"),
        data: { guid: $select.val() }
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: options.type,
        url: options.url,
        data: options.data,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)

            $(options.target).html(data);

        }
    });

    return false;

};
```

From that code, a button is added with the following View code:

```
<button id=@Model.Guid
    class="button default cycle-button"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#modalDiv"
    data-backdrop="static"
    data-keyboard="true"
    data-modal-modal="true"
    data-modal-controller="Fin_Movement_Type"
    data-modal-action="Create"
    data-modal-var-guid=@Model.Guid
    data-modal-var-modal=@ViewBag._modal>
    <span class="icon mif-plus"></span>
</button>
```

And by cicking on this button, the following .click() event should be fired...

```
$("[data-modal-modal='true']").click(function () {  ...  }
```

But it isn't.

Please Help me find where is the bug with my code... thank you.

Comment: Add desired code at the end of your success function.

Comment: I problably didnt understand the answers... the firing of the script is bi a clicking from a user, not auto... what did i missed?

Comment: And by the way, pay attention to put all semicolons and quotations. Any success?

Comment: At this moment i cant test the solution (I dont have my pc with me). But will test it as soon as i get home... But it seems by the answer that it does not expose the new data to the existing script without the 'hack' of re-insert the click event. The objective is to expose the new data to the existing javascript file without having to 're-insert' it... If i understood it correctly...

Comment: No, Check the edit, in the edited answer, you only need to correct your `on` codes in the js files when you need such functionality.

Comment: I added that comment before i saw the update X-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

It seems you need `live` functionality that has been removed from `jQuery`, but you can use `on` instead of that, this way:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click","[data-modal-modal='true']", function () {
        alert('clicked'); 
    });
});
```

**Original**

You can add your code at the end of your success method:

```
success: function (data) {
     console.log(data);
     $(options.target).html(data);
     $("[data-modal-modal='true']").on("click", function() {
         alert('clicked!');
     });
}
```

Also you can load the button with suitable script in `onclick` attribute, for example:

```
<button id="@Model.Guid"
    ...
    onclick="alert('clicked!');">
    <span class="icon mif-plus"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Does this means that there is no way to make the added data available to the existing script file without this "hack"? I call it hack because if i have multiple objects with multiple diferent attributes to call diferent scripts i have to add each to the script, and the script will have to be updated often. But no matter what, thank you for the answer.

Comment: you are welcome:) Also check the update for a better `Hack` ;)

Comment: Thank you, will try it when i get home. Thk

Comment: :) Hope you find it helpful

Comment: the answer did the trick, but the back problem still mantains... the DOM is not exposed to existing javascript file... I have a specific script that should be fired with a $("body").on("click", "textbox", function() {}), and it isnt :-/// damn

Comment: I have the script  `$(function () {
    $(document).on("click","a", function () {
        alert('clicked'); 
    });
});` and it works for all a tags even those that I dynamically added to the `DOM`. Can you reproduce the problem with such simple script?

Comment: After seeing your simple code I saw my mistake... I wrote my .on() method like this: `$('#idOfTextbox').on("input", function (e) {})` . It uses a .on(), but it does not bubble no where... (I think this is the problem)... I wrote `$("body").on("input", "#PosAmount", function (e) {})` and it worked just as expected... Once again.... many thanks!!! Sorry for my dumb questions.

Comment: It wasn't a dumb question at all, it was a good question :) +1